# ASP.NET crash minidumps

Tags: asp.net, iis

Whenever an ASP.NET 4.x Web application throws an unhandled exception in production, I would like a minidump that I can debug.

So far, the prevailing technique revolves around catching `Application_Error` in Global.asax and dumping the exception data in a text log file. That is sufficient for some bugs, but no replacement for a minidump. And here's a thing: *by the time you catch that exception, it's too late to generate a minidump*, since the precious execution context is gone.

So from the standpoint of minidump generation, *catching* that exception would be the wrong thing to do. But the ASP.NET framework *is* catching them on some level, doesn't it? I mean, the system JIT debugging window doesn't come up, so those exceptions don't really bubble all the way up.

It's not a one time thing; there's not a specific bug I want to debug; I want to monitor the run-time health of the whole ASP.NET province of our digital empire, ~100 homegrown apps on ~20 servers. So connecting with Visual Studio to the pool process in Prod and watching for the exception to come is not what I'm looking for. Also, I come from the dev side of things and have no admin on prod servers.

Any options out there, please? Paying money is not a problem.

EDIT: I had some hopes for `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, but that one doesn't suspend the failing thread. By the time the event fires, the thread with the exception is gone, nothing to minidump.

Comment: So you're looking for a tool that can generate minidumps when there's an unhandled exception in an ASP.NET site?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or a smart combination of settings within IIS itself.